# How to execute URL requests from an iOS application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, url

I want to send the following request to the server. The server already knows what to do with it, but how can I send it?

```
http://www.********.com/ajax.php?script=logoutUser&username=****
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a synchronous request you would do the following:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.********.com/ajax.php?script=logoutUser&username=****"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
//send it synchronous
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// check for an error. If there is a network error, you should handle it here.
if(!error)
{
    //log response
    NSLog(@"Response from server = %@", responseString);
}
```

**Update**: for doing an asynchronous request please refere to this [example](https://gist.github.com/106457)

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to recommend synchronous requests to beginner iOS developers who might not understand/appreciate the implications of blocking the UI. They just end up making unresponsive apps that might get them rejected from the app store. There's a post written by eskimo1 on the dev forums outlining all of your other options. The easiest way to implement asynchronous networking would be to use the new `NSURLConnection` async completion block method: `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler]`.

Comment: @JackLawrence that is your opinion, i would recommend the easiest solution, and if he then felt that he needs a more responsive solution he would search and or request for it later, anyways this was not a good reason for down-voting an answer, the answer is correct though it does not work with your opinion :)

Comment: @user1447339 please not, since jack lawrence just stated, you may need to use an asynchronous request later on in your application, you can use this example https://gist.github.com/106457, also please dont forget to accept the answer if it was helpful

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith True. Sorry about that. IMO the sendAsych block one is less lines of code, but it does introduce some fairly complex topics, so I concede on that point. I edited your post and made a trivial change so it would let me change my down vote. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @JackLawrence i didnt disagree with you :) i also updated the answer to include a simple example of an asynchronous request :)

Comment: Click the outline of the checkmark next to his answer so that it turns green.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
NSString *resp = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:enc error: &error];
```